# T-SQL - Why does REPLACE not work properly within Case?

Tags: sql, sql-server

See this SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/068e9/3/0
(MS Sql Server 2008)

Setup of schema is:

```
create table test_replace ( something varchar(50));

insert into test_replace(something) values('072 782 5343');
insert into test_replace(something) values('071 647 2342');
insert into test_replace(something) values('whatever@something.com');
```

Query is:

```
select case when CHARINDEX('@', something,0) > -1
then REPLACE(something,'@','@testtesttest')
else REPLACE(something,' ','') end as test1,
REPLACE(something,' ','') as test2
from test_replace
```

The second REPLACE in the CASE statement does not work (compare output of test1 to test2 when applied to the phone numbers). Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CHARINDEX` returns 0 when the string is not found (not -1 as you have)

Your query should be:

```
select case when CHARINDEX('@', something,0) > 0
then REPLACE(something,'@','@testtesttest')
else REPLACE(something,' ','') end as test1,
REPLACE(something,' ','') as test2
from test_replace
```

Answer (score 2):

CHARINDEX('@', '072 782 5343',0) not -1 but 0

so change -1 to 0 in condition

```
select case when CHARINDEX('@', something,0) > 0
then REPLACE(something,'@','@testtesttest')
else REPLACE(something,' ','') end as test1,
REPLACE(something,' ','') as test2
from test_replace
```